# Javascript ADDEVENTLISTENER CODE

Tags: javascript

So, hello everyone, if we have code like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
                          function() {
                            chrome.extension.sendMessage({
                                method: 'POST',
                                action: 'xhttp',
                                url: 'http://www.domain.com',
                                data: 'action=1'
                               },
                               function(data) {
                                 eval(data);
                               });
                          });
```

And www.domain.com server is closed for some IP, whatever it does not shows content it says : 404 Page Not Found  ,  but in real, we have some code in domain.com and if we use this  addeventlistener in our javascript, it gets code from domain.com and do something, can we read what is happening in this script? so let's say if there is var data= "test";   can we get this information what script is written on this eventlistener? since I think there is some array of data.

Comment: Your question isn't very comprehensible, but one thing that's sure is that if you get an error back from the server, there is no way to get any more data from it, you have to modify either your query or the server so it becomes valid.

Comment: Actually we run some functionality when we use addeecentlistener  but we don't know what scripts are there, we just know functionality, how can we understand script without logging on thei server?